# Rspec rails test devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec, devise

I was trying to test `devise` mailer via `rspec`.

Here is **devise_mailer_spec.rb**

require "rails_helper"

```
RSpec.describe Devise::Mailer do
  it "sends a confirmation email to correct email with custom text" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, confirmed_at: nil)
    confirmation_email = Devise.mailer.deliveries.last
    expect(user.email).to eq confirmation_email.to[0]
    expect(confirmation_email.body.to_s).to have_content 'You can confirm your account email'
  end
end
```

However, I got this error.

```
Failures:

  1) Devise::Mailer sends a confirmation email to correct email with custom text
     Failure/Error: expect(confirmation_email.body.to_s).to have_content 'You can confirm your account email'

       expected <p>Welcome adolfo@schoen.io!</p>

       <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

       <p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=sPMPQRe5SLDPgpakVy3J">Confirm my account</a></p>
        to respond to `has_content?`
     # ./spec/mailers/devise_mailer_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 8 minutes 38 seconds (files took 5.02 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/mailers/devise_mailer_spec.rb:4 # Devise::Mailer sends a confirmation email to correct email with custom text
```

I've set `binding.pry` into code, and I can make sure `confirmation_email.body.to_s` will throw

```
"<p>Welcome edgardo@heidenreich.name!</p>\n\n<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>\n\n<p><a href=\"http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=_qi3a9rsucm6YhG8CUjt\">Confirm my account</a></p>\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
expect(confirmation_email.body.encoded).to include 'You can confirm your account email'
```

Comment: `have_content` is a Capybara matcher, not an Rspec one, so it behaves slightly differently, but I don't think that was the issue in itself. I think it could potentially be the `.to_s` you were calling on the body.